# Get order id after Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: event-observer, sales-order, paypal, sales, paypal-express

I want an order Id  (not Increment Id) and quote after redirecting back from PayPal to my store.

For this purpose I am using `sales_order_place_after` event. But this event does not return order Id but getting an quote properly.

So is there **any other events which I can use to satisfied my requirement ?**

Answer (score 0):

Using the `sales_order_place_after` is the right idea in my opinion.

To get the order Id you can do:

```
$order = $observer->getOrder();
$orderId = $order->getEntityId();
```

To get the quote id from this order you can then do:

```
$quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
```

If you need full details of the quote and assuming you're using Magento 1 you can then call:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
```

Comment: I am not getting EntityId also :(

Comment: @Krupali what about `$order->getId()` ?

Comment: I try that very first.But not getting.

Comment: Is it good to use "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action event" ?

Comment: Can I use "paypal_express_place_order_success" event ?

Comment: @Krupali I don't think `paypal_express_place_order_success` is a native Magento event but you can use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` if you want

Comment: I think "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" event will not call if store is not using onepage checkout.